# How to use static columns from astyanax

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

Is there a way to create and use following column family with Astyanax:

```
CREATE TABLE mytest ( id text, subid text, clustering text, static_value text static, value text, PRIMARY KEY((id, subid), clustering));
```

If not, what are the best options for static columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Astyanax [Getting Started](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Getting-Started) section contains a section on how to ensure proper serialization by annotating key fields with the "ordinal" keyword:

```
// Annotated composite class
Class SessionEvent{
  private @Component(ordinal=0) String   sessiondId;
  private @Component(ordinal=1) UUID timestamp;

  public SessionEvent() {
  }

  public int hashCode() { ... }
  public boolean equals(Object o) { ... }
  public int compareTo(Object o) { ... }
}
```

Otherwise, the Astyanax repo also has [an example showing how to work directly with CQL3](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/blob/master/astyanax-examples/src/main/java/com/netflix/astyanax/examples/AstCQLClient.java).  To create your CF:

```
String CREATE_STATEMENT = "CREATE TABLE mytest ( id text, subid text, clustering text, static_value text static, value text, PRIMARY KEY((id, subid), clustering))";

try {
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  OperationResult<CqlResult<Integer, String>> result = keyspace
      .prepareQuery(EMP_CF)
      .withCql(CREATE_STATEMENT)
      .execute();
} catch (ConnectionException e) {
  logger.error("failed to create CF", e);
  throw new RuntimeException("failed to create CF", e);
}
```

The (CQL3) link above also contains example methods that demonstrate reading and inserting as well.

Comment: Yeah, there's a way to use composite column, but what about composite row key? I realize i could just use blob, and compose myself, just curious. Also what about static columns? I could create with sql statement, but then i will have to use cql to insert and so on. Is this correct?

Comment: There is a "getColumnByName" method on the ColumnList class that should work with static columns.  I would think that they would have a way to allow you to read via a composite partitioning key.  Honestly though, I haven't used Astyanax in a while, so I'm not sure how well its been updated to take advantage of some of the newer features of Cassandra 2.x.  So if you want to ensure that you'll be able to access via a composite partitioning key (id,subid) then using CQL is probably your best bet.